# Why is Typo3 not parsing <link ...>-tags back to <a ...>-tags?

Tags: html, parsing, typo3, typoscript, rte

At this moment I work on an own template using Typo3 7.6.2 expanding it step by step. As I finished the routine for a certain content type (->ctype, ->renderObj), I noticed that links, that are defined in the rte of the backend, are not processed correctly:

When I use the rte to define a link and toogle the text mode, it shows a valid HTML definition of a link:

[image: using the rte dialog to setup the link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lXpVt.png)

```
<a data-htmlarea-external="1" title="follow the link" target="_blank" href="http://stackoverflow.com">a link</a>
```

But in the generated page the link is defined using a link-tag:

```
<link http://stackoverflow.com _blank - "follow the link">a link</link>
```

---

The typoscript to include the contents, that were set by the rte, is the following:

```
BODYTEXT = TEXT
BODYTEXT.field = bodytext
```

---

- Can I somehow disable this parsing from a-tags to link-tags?
- Do I have to define the transformation from link-tag back to a-tag?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing the parseFunc. This is needed e.g. to parse the `<link>` tag generated by the RTE and transform it to HTML. Try adding it to your TypoScript:

```
BODYTEXT.parseFunc = < lib.parseFunc_RTE
```

css_styled_content needs to be installed for this to work.